# how to create personalized arrays from csv files in python

Tags: arrays, string, python-2.7, csv

I have two CSV files like this:

```
source,target
48,77
63,48
77,48
77,108
108,48
306,48
```

and

```
IDs,acronym,color,coord
48,MB,FF64FF,"[[308, 156, 268]]"
63,DMX,FFB3D9,"[[496, 208, 240]]"
77,SLD,FFC395,"[[404, 180, 200]]"
108,LSc,90CBED,"[[168, 164, 252]]"
306,SSp-ul5,188064,"[[160, 84, 312]]"
```

I need to convert that data in specific arrays

"Edges" should convine the data between "sources" and "targets" from the first CSV file, so:

```
Edges = [(48, 77), (63, 48), (77, 48), (77, 108), (108, 48), (306, 48)]
```

"labels" should contain the data of the "acronym" from the second CSV file arranged like this:

```
labels = [u'MB', u'DMX', u'SLD', u'LSc', u'SSp-ul5']
```

note: there should be a 'u' next to each acronym

"group" I think is easy using .append from the "color" column in the second CSV file

```
group = [FF64FF, FFB3D9, FFC395, 90CBED, 188064]
```

Each of the values of the column "coord" in the second CSV file should be divided in three arrays Xn,Yn and Zn with the respective values divided by 100 but keeping the decimals:

```
Xn = [3.08, 4.96, 4.04, 1.68, 1.60]
Yn = [1.56, 2.08, 1.80, 1.64, 0.84]
Zn = [2.68, 2.40, 2.00, 2.52, 3.12]
```

I think this can be done with regression expression using '[[|]]' and by separating the values with commas

And finally use the data contain in Xn ,Yn, Zn and Edges to create Xe, Ye and Ze. The first element in "Edges" is (48, 77) which corresponds to the first and third IDs (first column of the second CSV file), therefore, Xe for the first element on "Edges" should be (Xn[0], Xn[2], None) which is equal to [3.08, 4.04, None], so for all the Edges and coordinates Xn ,Yn, Zn I will have:

```
Xe = [3.08, 4.04, None, 4.96, 3.08, None, 4.04, 3.08, None, 4.04, 1.68, None, 1.68, 3.08, None, 1.60, 3.08, None]
Ye = [1.56, 1.80, None, 2.08, 1.56, None, 1.80, 1.56, None, 1.80, 1.64, None, 1.64, 1.56, None, 0.84, 1.56, None]
Ze = [2.68, 2.00, None, 2.40, 2.68, None, 2.00, 2.68, None, 2.00, 2.52, None, 2.52, 2.68, None, 3.12, 2.68, None]
```

If you can help me I will really appreciate it!
Cheers!

Comment: You are constructing a graph, but why are you using such an unusual format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
import ast

with open('1.csv', newline='') as csv1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csv1)
    field1 = next(reader1)
    Edges = [tuple(i)for i in reader1]
    print('Edges:', Edges)

with open('2.csv', newline='') as csv2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(csv2)
    field2 = next(reader2)
    data = [list(i)for i in zip(*reader2)]
    _, labels, group, coord = data
    coord = [ast.literal_eval(i)[0]for i in coord]
    X, Y, Z = [list(i)for i in zip(*coord)]
    Xn = [i/100for i in X]
    Yn = [i/100for i in Y]
    Zn = [i/100for i in Z]
    print('lables:', labels)
    print('group:', group)
    print(Xn, Yn, Zn, sep='\n')
```

out:

```
Edges: [('48', '77'), ('63', '48'), ('77', '48'), ('77', '108'), ('108', '48'), ('306', '48')]
lables: ['MB', 'DMX', 'SLD', 'LSc', 'SSp-ul5']
group: ['FF64FF', 'FFB3D9', 'FFC395', '90CBED', '188064']
[3.08, 4.96, 4.04, 1.68, 1.6]
[1.56, 2.08, 1.8, 1.64, 0.84]
[2.68, 2.4, 2.0, 2.52, 3.12]
```

Comment: Cool thanks! but when I run the code in my computer Xn, Yn and Zn are integers, how can I save the two decimals. Also, it is possible to keep an 'u' next to the elements in 'labels'. Finally, I edited the part of Xe, Ye and Ze. Dou you think you can help me with that? Cheers and thanks!

Comment: 'u' means unicode, in Python3, strings are unicode by default, there is no need to add 'u' as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else here covers most of the answer, so I won't rewrite their code.
Instead I'll just give you the structure to getting the end:

1. Clean and collect the information as given by everyone else to lists of:
   source-target pairs list, id list, acronym list, color list, x list, y list, z list.
2. To construct last lists, just look through your id list, matching the source-target pairs. Something like this:

   ```
   def find_location(id_list,  sample_id):
       for id_loc in xrange(len(id_list)):
           if id_list[id_loc] == sample_id:
               return id_loc
   def return_locations(source_destination_list):
       locations = [[find_location(item) for item in pair] for pair in source_destination_list]
       return locations
   ```

Then you use those locations (or positions) in the id_list to output your X, Y, and Z (since they'll be in the same positions in their own lists.
Adding 'None' and putting everything as single lists should be cake after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the csv file by using .split() method.

ex :

```
l = []

for line in lines: #lines = result of reading .csv file
   l.append(line.split(",")
```

This will return a table that contains all data.

If you want to access to third row fourth column you'll do :

```
l[3][4]
```

The first value of each column contain the column name, so you should start parsing at index 1.

For the final step, you have to transform string in list :

- Remove "[[" and "]]" form the str.
- Split the string by ", " -> str.split(", ")
- Use, in each created list, the same index to take the correspondant value